# По какой причине в Windows 7 сбрасывается запомненный пароль для rdp-сессии?

Tags: windows, windows-7, rdp

Здравствуйте, есть rdp-сервер на Windows server 2008r2 и не большой парк рабочих станций-клиентов на Windows 7. Аутентификация осуществляется по ntlm. При первоначальной настройке на ОС клиентов были созданы .rdp-файлы конфигурации, а также сохранены в локальное хранилище учетные данные для аутентификации на rdp-сервере. Проблема заключается в том, что через некоторое время на некоторых клиентских ОС, пароль из локального хранилища удаляется. И при установления rdp-сессии выводится запрос для ввода пароля. Добавлю, что это происходит в разные периоды на разных клиентских ОС. Есть клиенты, где это не происходило не разу, или происходило очень давно.